# Why is the domino server name incorrect when I preview design elements from the designer

Tags: xpages, lotus-domino

We have a domino server that is named (for example) SERVER1. When I preview a design element for the web from within designer the URL will be something like this:

http://www.SERVER1.com/APPNAME.nsf/m_XPAGENAME.xsp

but this will return a 404 error as the correct URL is

http://www.DOMINO.COMPANYNAME.com/APPNAME.nsf/m_XPAGENAME.xsp

This is really inconvenient. My admin and I are not sure why this is so; we believe we have set up something incorrectly. Can anyone please explain what is going on and possibly how to correct it?

Comment: This sort of thing can happen pretty easily when the common name in the server ID and the DNS name don't match, and you may or may not be able to adjust configuration documents to compensate as per Torsten's answer. As a workaround, though, you can add www.server1.com to the hosts file on your machine, and point it to the correct IP address for you server.

Answer (score 2):

If Internet Sites are disabled (default), then you have to check three things in the Server document of your server:

1. and on the "Internet Protocols - HTTP" tab: what is the "Host Name"
2. On the "General" Tab: what is the "Fully qualified Internet host name" of the server
3. under "Ports": what is the "Net address" entered for the port TCPIP

one of the three will most probably be the wrong... But be careful: don't change them without knowing, what they are neede for in your environment...

BUT: this for sure is a question for ServerFault and NOT for StackOverflow